# logo next to ul doesn't work and page's glitchy

Tags: html, navbar

I'm working on a navbar but it isn't working out as intended.

I want the word LOGO to appear on the left side of the navbar. But if i do this it all seems to go outside of the screen and not work anymore.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <div class="hallo"><h1>logo</h1></div>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li id="About"> <a href="#About"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
    <li id="Contact"> <a href="#Contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
    <li id="More"> <a href="#More"><strong>More</strong></a></li>
    <li id="Home"> <a href="#Home" color="coral"> <strong>Home</strong></a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What library does your navbar use, or is this custom CSS you wrote?  It will be difficult for the community to answer your question without more details.

Comment: Also, please read this article in the help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask